# Displaying Bing Imagery on Geoserver

Tags: bing-maps, geoserver, wms

My question revolves around Geoserver. I am currently using it to provide a web-map service, where-by Geoserver is pulling data from my Oracle database and displaying the Geometry in OpenLayers.

This works fine, but I have an end goal for my Geometry (points, lines, polygons) to no longer be displayed on a simple white background, but instead a map. I have been told that Bing imagery may be the way to go, but unfortunately I am rather inexperienced in this field.

Am open to any suggestions as to how I can implement this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Set the Bing Maps layer as the OpenLayers map's baselayer, then add the Geoserver WMS layer on top.  You'll want the top layer to have a transparent background so that the earth shows through.

Here are some examples.  View the page source on some of them:

1. http://docs.openlayers.org/library/introduction.html
2. http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/bing.html
3. http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/getfeatureinfo-control.html

The last one has the code you add to request Geoserver to send you back images with transparent backgrounds.